# Angular components not binding attributes after update from Angular 7 to Angular 10

Tags: angular, angular10

I have a really big Angular Project that was in version 7, I just finished updating it to version 10 but when I run ng serve I get a lot of these bind errors in my components.

"Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of i"

```
<li class="mb-0 list-inline-item">
    <i (click)="filterUsers();"
    [ngClass]="{'fa-spin': processing}"
    title="Refresh based on filters."
    class="fa fa-refresh cp"></i>
</li>
```

AS you'll see, there's nothing fancy going on there.
All I can find while searching for this is to import Common Module into the Component module but it's imported and these components were working before the update.

Does anyone have any ideas of what might be causing this behavior after the update?

Comment: Did you make sure to upgrade rxjs from 5 to 6 during this process?

Comment: @Willie Thanks for the idea. I checked and its updated  "rxjs": "6.6.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.1.0".

Comment: 1. Have you updated angular version one by one as Angular team recommend? 7-8-9-10? 2. Try to remove node_modules and do npm i to install all fresh packages.

Comment: Check [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=7.0-10.0) maybe can help.

Comment: Thanks @OscarLudick, I went through the upgrade guide but still have the same issue.